# if $\int_{0}^{1}|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx\to 0$ then $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$: True/false

Tags: real-analysis

Let  $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous real valued functions on $[0, \infty)$. Suppose $f_n(x)\to f(x) ~~~\forall x\in [0,\infty)$ and $f$ is integrable. Then

if $\int_{0}^{1}|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx\to 0$ then $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$: True/false

Im  not  able   to  find  a  counter example ?

Pliz help me

Comment: @henningmakholm Your first example that you deleted is valid if you let $f(1)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for all other $x$.  Then, $f_n(x)=x^n$ is continuous, has $f(x)$ as its limit, $f(x)$ is integrable, and $||f_n-f||_1\to 0$.  Yet, $x^n$ fails to converge uniformly.  So, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example where $f_n(x)$ does not converge at any point! Let $I_n=[\frac {i-1} {2^{n}},\frac i {2^{n}})$ for $1\leq i \leq 2^{n}$ and $n \geq 1$. Arrange the characteristic functions of these intervals in a sequence by first listing those with $n=1$, then the one's with $n=2$ etc. Then $\int_0^{1} |f_n(x)-0|\, dx \to 0$ but the functions do not converge even at one point.

Comment: thanks u sir @Kavi ram

Answer (score 3):

False .. $x^n$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$. Here the limit function is $f(x) = 0$ when $x \in [0,1)$ and $f(1) = 1$

But $\int_{0}^{1}|x^n-f(x)|dx\to 0$

Comment: (+1) Clear and concise.

Comment: Except that $x^n$ does not converge pointwise on $[0,\infty)$ as the question (rather pointlessly, to be sure) requires.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=xe^{-x}$, and then consider $f(x)=0$ and $f_n(x)=g(nx)$.